# Docker image "node" terminates before I can access it (using azure cli)

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-image, azure-container-instances, termination

I try to deploy my image that is based on node (node:latest) on azure. When I do it terminates automatically and does not let me do what I need to do with it.

My docker file:

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
COPY artillery-scripts.sh .
COPY images images
COPY src src
EXPOSE 80
RUN npm install -g artillery && \
    npm install faker && \
    npm install worker && \
    npm install -g node-fetch -save && \
    npm install -g https://github.com/preguica/artillery-plugin-metrics-by-endpoint.git
```

I have tried adding  `&& \ while true; do echo SLEEP; sleep 10; done` at the end so it wouldn't terminate automatically but that produces an error.

Any one know what this problem is?

Comment: I assume you posted not all of your Dockerfile, because of the missing `FROM` at the beginning? Could you please update your question.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry. It is "FROM node:latest"

Comment: ...and are you also missing the `CMD` at the end?

Comment: You need a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` at the end of your Dockerfile, e.g. `CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "sleep 3600"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably good to first try it all locally. It seems you misunderstand some fundamental parts of docker.
Writing something that will pause in your Dockerfile makes no sense at all, since that file is for building the image, not running the container.

Once you have the image, you can run one or more containers based on this image.
Usually you will want to put a CMD or ENTRYPOINT at the end that will tell the container what command to run. Read [this article](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-cmd-vs-entrypoint) which gives a pretty good explanation of both.

If you want to interact with the container look into the -i and -t (or short -it) flags of the [run command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/). When you run your container, you can also provide a command, this will override any command given in CMD or be appended to anything in ENTRYPOINT.
If you do not write an ENTRYPOINT or CMD it will default to running a shell.
However, if you run it without -it it will start the shell, consider it's work done and stop immediately.

Again if you would want to start a specific script for instance you can add a line to the end of your Dockerfile such as

```
CMD "node somefile.js"
```

So first build your image based on the dockerfile, then run the container based on the image:

```
docker build -t someImageName:someTag .
docker run -it someImageName:someTag // will run CMD, "node somefile.js" or:
docker run -it someImageName:someTag node // will override it and just run node
```

You can install docker locally and just do that all on your local machine, and once you get a feel for it, and once you are sure your dockerfile is correct see how to deploy it to azure. That way it is easier to debug and learn.

Extra tip: you wrote EXPOSE 80. Read the docs on EXPOSE and PUBLISH beacuse it can be confusing when you start out. EXPOSE is just there for documentation, it does NOT actually expose anything. If you would like to connect somehow to the container from the outside world you have to PUBLISH the port. This is done in the run command:

```
docker run -it someImageName:someTag -p 80:80 // the first is host port, the second is the container port.
```

Comment: You were right, I was misunderstanding that part of Docker. Mainly I was confusing RUN and CMD.
I needed to run my container in different regions and do some tests, then send me the file. I'm running docker on windows and I wrote a .sh file to do those things, but because I was on windows (and the image on linux) I could not run the file. For this I used dos2unix and it worked perfectly. From that I added a sh script.sh command to CMD (the script sent me the files through Dropbox).
My question was about the container on azure stopping, now I think that doing CMD ["bin", "bash"] would do it.